# Alamcenar variable desde una promesa

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente fragmento que lo que hace es almacenar en la variable objetoNew el objeto que se obtiene como respuesta de la promesa .then(res=>.....

```
var objetoNew ={};
firebaseService.tiendas().then(res=>{
  console.log('method1', res);
  objetoNew = res;
})
console.log(objetoNew);
```

cuando hago el console.log dentro del then, si me aparecen los datos, pero al hacer el console de objetoNew fuera de la promesa esta varible sige vacia, 
Es decir que no me esta sobreescribiendo la variable global(objetoNew) desde el then.

Muchas gracias amigos!

Comment: el console.log es inmediato. La respuesta de la promesa no lo es. La variable no se va a actualizar hasta que se resuelva.

Comment: entonces como podria acomodar el codigo para que si suceda

Answer (score 0):

Buen día colega, sería bueno que por favor colocaras todo el código completo para tener mas referencia de lo que podría estar sucediendo pero a simple vista parece que tu problema es que estas perdiendo el scope del resultado al resolverse el llamado. Prueba esto y me comentas:

```
var newObject = {};
newObject = firebaseService.tiendas().then( res => {
return res;
});
console.log(objetoNew);
```

Comment: Al hacer el console.log me saler Promise{<pendind>}

Comment: Ok, ahora lo que debes hacer es construir el resto de la app o eventos han de venir a partir de la resolución de la promesa. Tal y como te explica @amenadiel en su respuesta.

Comment: Ya me sirvio, efectivamente era lo que dijiste, mcuhas gracias por ayuarme!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos maneras de controlar el flujo.

**A)** Envolviendo todo el código en la primera promesa:

```
var objetoNew ={};
firebaseService.tiendas().then(res=>{
  console.log('method1', res);
  objetoNew = res;
  return res;
}).then((res) => { // esto es redundante porque ya tienes la global objetoNew

  // haces cosas con objetoNew
});
```

**B)** Usando async/await

Como `await` sólo puede usarse dentro de una función `async` tendrías que encapsular toda la lógica en una función. Algo como:

```
async function logicaDeObjetoNew() {
   var objetoNew = await firebaseService.tiendas();
   console.log(objetoNew);

   // haces cosas con objetoNew
}

logicaDeObjetoNew();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvio mucho, ahpra ya entiendo mas sobre las funciones asincronas, mcuhas gracias de neuvo!